# Может ли github служить какой-то мало-мальской защитой от  нарушения прав copy©Rights?

Tags: юридические-аспекты, git, авторские-права, github

Я имею в виду ту часть исходников, которые находятся в `public`, с тем что `private` и так все ясно. Я так понимаю по дате создания `репозитория` и `коммитам` можно определить кто, что да как.

Comment: Если хотите защитить свой программный код от нарушения прав - храните этот код дома, у себя на винчестере.

Comment: @istem, ну это тоже крайности, если разрабатывает более одного человека. Закрытого репозитория (своего или гитхабовского) с ssh-доступом вполне хватит.

Answer (score 6):

Copyright и git - не имеют друг к другу никакого отношения. Copyright это юридический инструмент, а git это репозиторий для хранения исходников (и не только).

То что исходники лежат открыто не дает никому права использовать их по своему усмотрению. Если вы увидели на парковке машину с открытыми дверями и ключами - это не дает вам права использовать машину. В случае использования машины - это будет квалифицировано как угон со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

То же самое и здесь.

Comment: да, но `авторство` ведь установить как-то проще выйдет. Исходники в общую базу МВД не заносятся...

Comment: В этом контексте - может быть. Только не забудьте сопроводить текст copyright'ом и условиями использования

Comment: `В случае использования ... будет квалифицировано как угон` — не будет, ибо [неправомерное завладение автомобилем или иным транспортным средством без цели хищения](http://www.ukru.ru/code/08/166/index.htm). Хищение же — это *«совершенные с корыстной целью противоправные безвозмездное изъятие и (или) обращение чужого имущества ... причинившие ущерб собственнику или иному владельцу этого имущества»* (согласно [постановлению Верховного суда](http://www.vsrf.ru/Show_pdf.php?Id=7236)).То есть если машину не бить и не продавать, то это не угон по определению.

Answer (score 5):

Если мы говорим о РФ, российский суд может с легкостью не принять к рассмотрению дату создания электронных документов на даже российском сервере (дату знаете ли и нарисовать можно).

Юридически эффективнее будет зарегистрировать программу в "Общероссийском реестре программ для ЭВМ" (стоит чуть больше тысячи рублей, прикладывается распечатка исходников) и/или воспользоваться классическим способом с отправкой исходников самому себе в заказном конверте с описью (конверт не вскрывать).

Comment: @Maris, тогда совет: избегайте посредников, коих много в интернетах и IRL, предлагающих "запатентовать" программу тысяч за 40 рублей. Вся инфа есть на www1.fips.ru, нужно всего-то заполнить анкету, приложить описание + исходники и оплатить пошлину (~1200 руб.)/